# React function components and inline functions

Tags: reactjs

I found a lot of samples when working with class component's and calling inline functions in JSX. Here you can bind the function in the constructor. How do you do the same with function compoents? I have following that fails with "Cannot read property of undefined":

[image]

Comment: Add your code also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### this keyword

With functional components we don't use `this` keyword at all :)

```js
getServerityLevelText(1)
```

#### tip with memoization

One more thing here about "methods" of functional component: if this "methods" placed in the body of functional component, they re-creates every render (and if you pass them to children, they re-renders too, because of props update).

So if you  don't want to use class and you like optimized code, you have to wrap your "methods" like `getServerityLevelText` in `useCallback` React hook.

```js
const getServerityLevelText = useCallback((severityLevel) => {
  return "Works";
}, []);
```

Comment: I have no idea what I am doing today. I started out with out this and got the error. Just tested again and your absolutly right. It works without this. Not sure what I was doing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With arrow functions there is no binding of `this`. Instead you can refer to the local variable `getSeverityLevelText` directly without prefixing it with `this.`.

Comment: Actually just testetd again. No idea what I have been doing. It works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const App = () => {

  const handleOnClick = () => 
  {
    console.log("Here");
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={handleOnClick}>Here</Button>
    <div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```